# Problema com o Java

Tags: java, jvm

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando tento abrir um arquivo BAT, com o seguinte código:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET PASTA_BASE=%~dp0
START CMD /C %PASTA_BASE%\client.js -a DESE -p Terminal -x
```

É apresentado a seguinte mensagem de erro: "Could not create the Java virtual machine." (imagem com o erro está anexo a essa pergunta), andei pesquisando e vi que é um problema herdado pela SUN na VM, mais não sei mais o que posso ajustar no fonte para arrumar isso, quem topa esse desafio?

Comment: Quais são suas variáveis de ambiente `PATH` e `JAVA_HOME`? O que é que tem nesse `client.js`?

Comment: WshSysEnv("JRE_HOME")  = ".\\runtime\\jre";
var JRE_PATH     = WshSysEnv("JRE_HOME");